# Find where Java loads files from?

Tags: java

I was just wondering if there is a way to find out where a java program will be searching for files.

I am trying to load a settings file with `FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("ldaplookup.ini");` but it is throwing a File not found error. The ini file is in the same folder as the class file but i am assuming it is searching somewhere else.

Thanks, -Pete

Comment: You should use Class.getResourceAsStream() method instead ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FileInputStream looks up the file relative to the path of execution.  If the resource file is in the same folder as the class, you can try using:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("ldaplookup.ini");
```

Comment: The good thing is that this method also works when the class is in a jar, so it works the same in the IDE or when deployed.

Answer (score 5):

Java loads files from the current working directory for a relative path.  If you want to see what is, try this:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is showing C:\Windows\System32, which seems a little odd to me. Is there a way i can change where it is looking for files? or would it be better if i just put in the absolute path to my ini file?

Comment: Actually, for a real program you are going to distribute, you want to use relative paths.  How are you invoking (command line, ide, etc)?

Comment: it is a servlet hosted on a web server invoked by the Post method from a web page.

Comment: OK, in that case, you have 2 options.  If the .ini file is fairly static and you want to distribute it with your classes, see Michael's response below using Class.getResourceAsStream().  If you want to change it independently, and you normally would for an ini, try setting the working directory of the servlet in the web server configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Since "`new FileInputStream("ldaplookup.ini");`" is equivalent to "`new FileInputStream("./ldaplookup.ini");`", you could try:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 3):

A much more reliable method to read files that are distributed with your classes is to use [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) - it will look in the directory in the classpath where the class you're calling it on is situated, and it will even work when everything is packaged in a JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

Not direct answer but a helpful alternative:

You can use a [resource bundle](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) instead.

```
 rename ldaplookup.ini to ldaploopup.properties
```

And load it with:

```
 ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ldaplookup");


 String s = bundle.getString("url");
```

ResourceBundle search in the classpath for a .properties file among [other strategies](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html).

Etc. etc.

p.s.

To know what is the base path for your program try ( as suggested before: )

```
System.out.println(new File("."));
```